# How to raise Windows.Forms.WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler event in derived class

Tags: vb.net

I am converting a C# program to VB,Net. The conversion created the following line:

```
Me.axWebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += New Windows.Forms.WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(AddressOf Me.axWebBrowser1_DocumentComplete)
```

This line creates the following error message:

> Error  17  'Public Event DocumentCompleted(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs)' is an event, and cannot be called directly. Use a 'RaiseEvent' statement to raise an event.

I can not find whether there is a RaiseEvent statement in the Systems class which I can use to raise the event. I can not do it in my derived class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not trying to raise the event, you're trying to subscribe to it.

In VB.NET this is done using an [**AddHandler statement**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7taxzxka.aspx):

```
AddHandler Me.axWebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted, AddressOf Me.axWebBrowser1_DocumentComplete
```

---

Also a statement isn't located inside a class, namespace or library. A statement is a line, or multiple lines, of code that goes together. So, not related to your problem, but you can read about the [**RaiseEvent statement**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fwd3bwed.aspx).

Comment: Visual Vincent,     That corrected the error I listed, but it exposed 3 other errors which I will post as a separate question.  Thank you..

Comment: @LarryHowardMittman : No problem! But does my code generate the errors, or is it elsewhere in your code? Because unless my answer works I will continue to help you here.

Comment: the new errors are in another portion of the code and they had been masked by this solved error. They are not related to your answer. The problem I have is that the original C# program has been placed through the Telerik converter to generate VB.NET code. The boss wants to convert all C# to VB,NET because that is the shop standard.

Comment: @LarryHowardMittman : Okay. Then I wish you the best of luck solving them! Just ask another question if you run into problems. Have a nice day!